# Subdivision modifier is making artefact when applied with array modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers

Subdivision modifier is making artefact when applied with array modifier:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe don't use "merge" in the array modifier. If not that this is du to individual element toplogoy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the merge option in the array modifier:

[image]

So don't use it.

Or if you want to merge, merge at the end, adding a weld modifier:

[image]

An other possibility, is to invert the modifier: subdivision then array.

[image]

Note that you have the same issue at many places, lukily, you can fix it by adding a subdivision:

[image]

Comment: OK thanks, for the information, fixed my issue.